# How to Change Plotting Symbol in rCharts rPlot?

Tags: r, symbols, rcharts, polychart

I want to change the plotting symbol in my rCharts rPlot from the default circle.  Specifically, I'd like to be able to use a triangle pointing up, a triangle pointing down, and a square. I only want 1 symbol at a time in any given graph, I'm just trying to figure out the right argument to make that happen.  Here is the sample code:

```
    p6 <- rPlot(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars, type = 'point', color = "gear")
    p6
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing this as an option in [polycharts](https://github.com/polychart/polychart2/wiki), but you could do this with [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) and hPlot:

```
p6 <- hPlot(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars, type = 'scatter', group = "gear")
p6
```

[image]

Comment: Does this solution answer your question?